# Add view_id to page in notebook

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-9

it's possible to add an view_id to page in notebook?

Like this:

```
<notebook>
    <page name="page_details">
        <!--Call an view by view_id-->
    </page>
</notebook>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define any kind of view in a page so directly write view defination inside that page.

e.g.

```
<page name="abc">
    <tree>
      ....
    </tree>
    <form>
        .....
    </form>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a view for a x2many field present in the model, in order to show a specific tree view of that field, or the form view of the related object.

You can do that in the way of @irfankhan-juneja's answer, or by using field context to *Call* those views:

```
    <field name="xxx" context="{'form_view_ref': 'module_name.view_form_id', 'tree_view_ref': 'module_name.view_tree_id'}" />
```

But you can't insert just *any* view you like.